# Why `*{display:block; margin:0 auto; }` in css to display all the css code on the web?

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
*{
    display:block; 
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

#it is no use to show all the css and html code here.

Why  `*{display:block;  margin:0 auto; }` in css to display all the css code on the web?
If  `*{display:block;  margin:0 auto; }` was deleted on the html,no such error now.
What result in the effect？

[image]

Please try the whole html file.

```
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
<style>
*{
    display:block; 
    margin:0 auto;
}
body{    

    width:900px;
    height:50px;
    border:solid 4px green;  
}

#d2{    
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
#d21,#d22,#d23{
    width:33%;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid red;
}
select,input{
    width:150px;
    height:auto;
}    
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="d2">
    <div id="d21">
        <select id="id_select"  name="s1">
            <option>==> please select <==</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="d22">
        <input  type="button" value="start" onclick="start()">
    </div>
    <div id="d23">
        <input   type="button" value="stop" onclick="stop()">
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you closed the style tag? `</style>`

Comment: closed the style tag .

Comment: * selector won't accept `display:block`. every elements in html except `<a>, <small> <img> ` and more..... are block elements. So no need to add 'display:block' to '*' element.  Remove the `display:block` and check the result

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to use the universal selector to set everything to display block. But the reason why the css code is showing up is because the "Head" element's inherent property is display: none. But you are overriding it to be display block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*` CSS selector selects *all* elements. This means that it includes the `<style>` element, as well as the `<head>` element, which the style tag lives it. Both of these are hidden by default by your browser.

By adding `display: block`, you are overriding the default `display: none` for all element, as shown in Chrome Developer Tools screenshot:

[Chrome Developer Tools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT7aY.png)

The direct equivalent of this would be to add this to your CSS:

```
head, style {
  display: block;
}
```

## Workaround

In order to force all elements to be displayed block, and centered, you may want to select just the ones that live inside of the `<body>` tag like so:

```
body * {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`<style>...</style>` is also HTML element. So by using `*` selector in CSS you also select `<style>` element and apply appropriate styling. `<style>`'s default style is `display:none` so by applying `display:block` you actually make it visible.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this answer before I posted. This is the reason for this behavior. Check our my answer for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

1. `*` selector won't accept `display:block`. Every elements in html except `<a> <small> <img>` and more..... are block elements. So no need to add `display:block` to `*` element.  Remove the `display:block` and check the result.
2. The * selector can also select all elements inside another element, but `<a> <small> <span>` are elements. So the css syntax become an error.

Comment: But  <a>, <small> <img> can accept `display:block` in their's css code.

Comment: yes it will accept, why you need do add `display:block` to the `*` element. That's not necessary. :)

Comment: Why the css code totally displayed when `display:block` added on `* `element?

Comment: The `*` selector can also select all elements inside another element, but `<a> <small> <span>' are elements. So the css syntax become an error.